# JDBC SQL command not properly ended

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Below is my jdbc Query:

```
Connection con = DB_Connection.get_dbConnectionSingleTime("TESTA2", "ao3652", "reset123", "Oracle");
    String premium = "Premiums";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM ELP_COUNTRY,ELP_COUNTRY_Tax where"+
 "ELP_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID=Elp_Country_Tax.Country_Id"+  
 "and ELP_COUNTRY.DESCRIPTION=? and GETENGLISHDESCFROMLISTITEM(ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.TAX_TYPE_ID)=?"+
 "and ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.DEALER_ID is  null order by ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.Effective_Date DESC";
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------^
    try(PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(query)){
        pst.setString(1, Country);// Set the input
        pst.setString(2, premium);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        rs = pst.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.next());
        }
    }
```

The above code is through JDBC which is throwing sql command not properly ended.

And below is my sql query which is working fine

```
SELECT *FROM ELP_COUNTRY,ELP_COUNTRY_Tax where 
 ELP_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID=Elp_Country_Tax.Country_Id  
 and ELP_COUNTRY.DESCRIPTION='Brasil' and GETENGLISHDESCFROMLISTITEM(ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.TAX_TYPE_ID)='Premiums'
 and ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.DEALER_ID is  null order by ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.Effective_Date DESC
```

So can any one suggest me some of the corrections I need to do in jdbc query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append spaces at the end of each string:

```
"SELECT * FROM ELP_COUNTRY,ELP_COUNTRY_Tax where"+
 "ELP_COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID=Elp_Country_Tax.Country_Id"+  
 "and ELP_COUNTRY.DESCRIPTION=? and GETENGLISHDESCFROMLISTITEM(ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.TAX_TYPE_ID)=?"+
 "and ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.DEALER_ID is  null order by ELP_COUNTRY_TAX.Effective_Date DESC"
```

for example this:

```
 " .......  where"+
 "ELP_COUNTRY ......."
```

gives this string:

```
" ...... whereELP_COUNTRY....."
```

---

and this:

```
 ....... X_TYPE_ID)=?"+
 "and ELP_COU ..........
```

results in:

```
....... X_TYPE_ID)=?and ELP_COU ..........
```

---

If you insert a space after `where`:

```
 " .......  where "+
 "ELP_COUNTRY ......."
```

you'll get proper SQL statement:

```
 " ...... where ELP_COUNTRY....."
```